# How does Hildebrands proof of the prime number theorem via large sieve work?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How does the sieve inequality (I may not know the most general form) lead to the distribution of primes? To me, these concepts do not seem to be related. Can their connection be described in a sentence or two?

Relevant article: A. Hildebrand, *The prime number theorem via the large sieve*, Mathematika 33 (1986), 23-30.